# Random failure of creating a New Cassandra Cluster using OpsCenter

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax, opscenter

OpsCenter version: 5.1.0 and
DSE Version: 4.6.0

Creating a brand new cluster by using OpsCenter directly, gives us the following error. It randomly works with the same settings but 95% of the times it fails with the same error. Opscenter is running on its own box but sharing the same Security groups as the cluster instances. For good measure, I have opened up all TCP ports to all IPs. The following is the stack trace of the error from the opscenterd.log:

*2015-03-19 10:06:12+0000 []  INFO: Starting provisioning process
2015-03-19 10:06:12+0000 []  INFO: Starting installation phase of cluster provisioning

2015-03-19 10:06:13+0000 []  WARN: HTTP request http://10.x.x.x:61621/alive? failed: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.

2015-03-19 10:06:13+0000 []  INFO: Beginning install of OpsCenter agent to 54.x.x.x

2015-03-19 10:06:26+0000 []  WARN: HTTP request http://10.x.x.x:61621/alive? failed: Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.

2015-03-19 10:06:31+0000 []  INFO: Agent for ip 10.x.x.x is version None
2015-03-19 10:06:31+0000 []  INFO: Agent for ip 10.x.x.x is version u'5.1.0'
2015-03-19 10:07:23+0000 []  INFO: Successfully installed agent and dse on node 10.x.x.x

2015-03-19 10:07:23+0000 []  INFO: Beginning "stop" phase of cluster provisioning

2015-03-19 10:07:25+0000 []  WARN: Marking request '10.x.x.x: /ops/stop' (f6708fa2-b45f-42b4-b992-90a82b460ac7) as failed: /usr/sbin/service dse stop failed

```
    exit status: 1
    stdout:
    log_daemon_msg is a shell function
    Cassandra 2.0 and later require Java 7 or later.
```

2015-03-19 10:07:25+0000 [] ERROR: Failed to stop node 10.x.x.x: /usr/sbin/service dse stop failed

```
    exit status: 1
    stdout:
    log_daemon_msg is a shell function
    Cassandra 2.0 and later require Java 7 or later.
```

2015-03-19 10:07:25+0000 []  WARN: Marking request 'stop stage' (0b6fcb6b-96ba-404e-a484-b4b6b167b309) as failed: Failed to stop node 10.x.x.x: /usr/sbin/service dse stop failed

```
    exit status: 1
    stdout:
    log_daemon_msg is a shell function
    Cassandra 2.0 and later require Java 7 or later.
```

2015-03-19 10:07:25+0000 [] ERROR: Stop stage failed: Failed to stop node 10.x.x.x: /usr/sbin/service dse stop failed

```
    exit status: 1
    stdout:
    log_daemon_msg is a shell function
    Cassandra 2.0 and later require Java 7 or later.
```

2015-03-19 10:07:25+0000 []  WARN: Marking request 'provision' (daf1c15d-92e3-40b0-83ca-34d548ea835b) as failed: Stop stage failed: Failed to stop node 10.x.x.x: /usr/sbin/service dse stop failed

```
    exit status: 1
    stdout:
    log_daemon_msg is a shell function
    Cassandra 2.0 and later require Java 7 or later.
```

2015-03-19 10:07:25+0000 [] ERROR:
2015-03-19 10:07:25+0000 [] ERROR: Cluster provisioning failed: Exception: Stop stage failed: Failed to stop node 10.x.x.x: /usr/sbin/service dse stop failed

```
    exit status: 1
    stdout:
    log_daemon_msg is a shell function
    Cassandra 2.0 and later require Java 7 or later.
```

2015-03-19 10:07:25+0000 [] ERROR: Failed to provision cluster: Cluster provisioning failed: Exception: Stop stage failed: Failed to stop node 10.x.x.x: /usr/sbin/service dse stop failed

```
    exit status: 1
    stdout:
    log_daemon_msg is a shell function
    Cassandra 2.0 and later require Java 7 or later.
```

2015-03-19 10:07:25+0000 []  WARN: Marking request 28c021fd-d21a-4fed-bb5c-a4fe17d362e0 as failed: Cluster provisioning failed: Exception: Stop stage failed: Failed to stop node 10.x.x.x: /usr/sbin/service dse stop failed

```
    exit status: 1
    stdout:
    log_daemon_msg is a shell function
    Cassandra 2.0 and later require Java 7 or later.
```

2015-03-19 10:07:41+0000 []  WARN: Unable to find a matching cluster for node with IP [u'fe80:0:0:0:2000:aff:feeb:31c7%2', u'10.x.x.x', u'0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1', u'127.0.0.1']; the message was [u'5.1.0', u'/1947480708/conf']. This usually indicates that an OpsCenter agent is still running on an old node that was decommissioned or is part of a cluster that OpsCenter is no longer monitoring.

Appreciate any help!
Thanks in advance
Harsha

Comment: Would just like to add that all of this is on Amazon. Also, I am using the Default AMI that Opscenter provides. (ami id - 814ec2e8) so the error about Java 7 etc increases the confusion a bit as all of this is DSE default with preinstalled software inside.

Comment: Are you sure you’re using the default AMI? 814ec2e8 is a rather old one (updated in 2013), and OpsCenter 5.1 defaults to ami-6139e708 instead.

Comment: ami-814ec2e8 Yes this is the ID.. I even upgraded to 5.1.1. I add a new cluster or node shows the same.

Answer (score 6):

OpCenter developer here. I make the OpsCenter provisioning features go zoom (or splat occasionally as you've seen). It is with sadness and shame that I must tell you that you're hitting a bug.

The Datastax AMI version 2.4 used by OpsCenter provisioning (https://github.com/riptano/ComboAMI/tree/2.4) does quite a bit of work at boot time via startup scripts. One of those tasks is to set up some gpg repository keys used to validate packages. Intermittently that process can fail, breaking package installs and leading to the series of errors that you're seeing. This failure is intermittent and has greatly increased in frequency recently. If you check /home/ubuntu/datastax-ami/ami.log you should see the gpg key failures that begin the rest of the failure chain.

Unfortunately, this error is pretty far down the technology stack and is difficult to manually work around. If you just need to provision a single cluster you can retry until you get a good run.  Otherwise your best best is  to manually launch the instances and use local provisioning to deploy dse/dsc to their private ip addresses:

- Launch instances using ami-ada2b6c4 (assuming you're in us-east-1)

  - Make sure to add the instances to the OpsCenterSecurity group.
  - Make sure you have the private half of the keypair you use (you'll need it during local provisioning)
  - On the instance data page, hit the advanced pulldown and add the following userdata as text "--raidonly --java7"
- Do a local-provisioning run against the private-ip's

Not a super-simple workaround.  I wish your experience with OpsCenter this time around was more awesome. The good news is I'm on this bug and it will be fixed in an upcoming point release.

Edit: No longer necessary to manually remove /etc/security/limits.d/cassandra.conf

Comment: Hi Mike. Great job with the Opscenter tool and thank you for your response. Is this bug fixed in Opscenter 5.1.1 ? I would love to be able to use Opscenter to provision clusters effortlessly. I tried a couple of times with 5.1.1 and it hasnt given me that error again.  Also as a feature request kindly give opscenter the option of creating cassandra nodes and clusters in a VPC on Amazon.

Comment: The fix hasn't been pushed, and when it goes it won't be a release but will be a automatically downloaded configuration file. I'll ping here when I get it out, we've had some good community contributions to ComboAMI that I want to land before we bake a new AMI. As to VPC, I can't talk about potential future features but we know it's something people want so keep an eye on the changelogs.

Comment: Local provisioning method gives same problems
 ERROR [Initialization] Error connecting via JMX: java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused] INFO [main] Creating stomp connection to 172.31.19.2:61620 INFO [StompConnection receiver] Reconnecting in 0s INFO [Initialization] Starting Jetty server: {:join? false, :ssl? false, :host nil, :port 61621}

Comment: Sadly, the AMI fix for OpsCenter 5.x was never released. However, OpsCenter 6.0 is out now and includes revamped provisioning feature called LCM. LCM is no longer tightly coupled to a particular AMI... you can install it on any supported operating system (Red Hat, Ubuntu, etc) by launching target instances with any public AMI.

Answer (score 0):

if its just complaining about java then install the java 7 preferably datastax wants oracle jdk and jre. you might already have java 7 and another version on your nodes but java 7 is not the default version. to change this do:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-7-oracle
```

which is a command you can script to run with ssh so you dont have to log in to each node

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. That is the weird part, the ami i am using to launch the cassandra cluster is provided by OpsCenter by default.. which is like an appliance of sorts. Plug and play. http://aws.amazon.com/amis/datastax-auto-clustering-ami-2-2
The whole purpose would be defeated if I will have to manually intervene to the launching of nodes using OpsCenter. But let me try your suggestion and get back here.. Thanks again.

Comment: actually if its a ready ami and you are also having connection refused problems you might want to check the security group that you are assigning to your instances so that port rules for required ports by cassandra are available

Comment: My Security Group has All TCP Ports open to 0.0.0.0/0. Both Opscenter and the cassandra nodes belong to the same security group so they should be able to talk to each other without issues. I am also able to telnet on that 61621 port from Opscenter to Cassandra node i.e.