# Why OpsCenter doesn't allow me create nodes on the default EC2 Network anymore?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, amazon-vpc, opscenter

I've had to update our DataStax OpsCenter service from **5.1.3** to **5.2.1** because when I tried to add a new node to our Cassandra Cluster (**DSE 4.6.6** on Amazon EC2) it said that *"No nodes were available to retrieve a configuration from."*

Updating to 5.2.1 fixed that issue, but it created a new one; now the VPC ID doesn't allow me to create nodes on the EC2 default network, it's not shown entirely, it only allows me to choose one of the 2 VPC's we already have.

It seems that they've added VPC support on 5.2.0...

> Support for AWS VPC when creating clusters/nodes in the EC2 Cloud.
>   (OPSC-3429)
>   http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/release_notes/opscReleaseNotes520.html

But it shouldn't be mandatory, since on the "Add node" documentation it also says the following...

> A list of current VPC IDs in the region in which the current OpsCenter instance is built. Both the VPC ID and the network range are displayed. **The AWS default VPC ID is also indicated.** The VPC ID list is prepopulated after entering your EC2 credentials. An AWS VPC (Amazon Web Services Virtual Private Cloud) holds one contiguous network range that can be subdivided into subnets. 
>   http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2//opsc/online_help/opscAddNodeCloudCluster.html

I need to create nodes on the default EC2 network, since the other nodes are already there and migrating to VPC is not an option for us right now (perhaps in a not-so-near future we'll have time to do so).

- Is this a bug on OpsCenter 5.2.1?
- Something that I need to update on our settings?
- Is there a workaround to create the server in the old-way? (ie, downgrade and fix the configuration node error somehow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpsCenter developer here, I wrote the VPC feature. Can you screenshot your add-node form with the VPC dropdown expanded (feel free to black out any aws-id's or information you consider sensitive)?

One clarification which may be obvious or may be the root of your problem. The "default EC2 network" aka "EC2 classic" *is* in a VPC, which OpsCenter (and much AWS documentation) calls the default VPC. This should be represented in the VPC dropdown as something like "vpc-123456 10.0.0.0/24 (default)". If you select this VPC, you're not "migrating to VPC" or launching nodes in a different place. You're launching in what is variously called "EC2 classic" or "default vpc" which is where your existing nodes currently exist. You can verify this by comparing the network listed, which should match the network that your nodes are already launched in.

If you're not seeing any VPC option labelled as "default" then you may have stumbled on a bug.

Comment: On the "add node" popup, I have a select combobox for VPC ID, and we do have 2 VPCs created which are shown, but Cassandra is not on one of those, and thus I cannot create a node outside (on the Default VPC).

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the "New Cluster" popup, the Add Node looks almost exactly the same; the 3 VPCs on the list, are actual VPCs (I've created a new one a few minutes ago), but as I've said before, we created the cluster on the Default VPC (EC2 Classic): http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=r1eijl&s=8#.VgX5eXsxUgQ

Comment: Ok, that screenshot does seem to lack a VPC with a "default" label, so it looks like you've stumbled on a genuine bug here.

Comment: I've filed OPSC-6706 in our internal bug-tracker to get it fixed in a future version.

The workaround will be to manually launch nodes using the AWS console, and then use "local provisioning" to their private-ip addresses in order to get them installed/configured. The procedure for this workaround is described in another stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141862/random-failure-of-creating-a-new-cassandra-cluster-using-opscenter/29174929#29174929